# Not able to understand (struct Stack* stack)

Tags: stack

```
struct Stack* create(int max) { 
struct Stack *stack = (struct Stack*)malloc(sizeof(struct Stack)); 
stack->maxSize = max; 
stack->top = -1; 
stack->array = (int*)malloc(stack->maxSize * sizeof(int));
return stack; }
 int isFull(struct Stack* stack) 
 { 
       if(stack->top == stack->maxSize - 1)
 {
         printf("STACKOVERFLOW\n");
 }
        return stack->top == stack->maxSize - 1; 
 }
```

What is the use of struct Stack* stack in this question?

I am trying to understand stack but can't understand why dow we have to use this struct Stack* stack

Comment: You'll need to tag the specific language being used here, C for e.g.

Answer (score 0):

The code is dynamically allocating the internal array that it is (presumably*) using as a stack.  This keeps the implementer from having to predefine one or more fixed length arrays which would be wasteful.  The use of a dynamically allocated data structure makes the code flexible.  Presumably this is straight C code and the implementation of the code as a struct gives you advantages approaching that of an actual object in an actual object oriented language (partial [but not real] data hiding for example).

*I have to say presumably because the code is nor implementing any definite stack operations aside from checking if the stack is full (isFull() ).